# Build SDL sources for iOS developement with Xcode 12

Tags: ios, xcode, sdl, xcode12

I am trying to setup an SDL iOS project with Xcode 12 but I fail.

- From the SDL source, I cannot build the lib itself unless if I exclude "arm64" (Excluded Architecture / Any iOS simulator SDK)
- When I try to build my project for a simulator I get some `Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64` ...
- When I try to build my project for "any iOS device" I get `Undefined symbols for architecture arm64` ...

Is there any up-to-date tutorial to build an SDL project for iOS with Xcode 12 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time searching, I finish with :

- Build the SDL with exclude "arm64" (Excluded Architecture / Any iOS simulator SDK -- debug and release)
- exclude arm64 for your project as well
- Of course add libsdl2.a to linked libraries in your project
- **Add `Metal.framework` and `CoreBluetooth.framework`** to to linked libraries in your project !
- At last, I had a message for a missing `Bundle version string (short)` in the plist. Add it and you are done !

Build and run on your emulator and device !